# fblualib installation with luarocks

Tags: torch, luarocks

I am trying to install fblualib and facing this issue that I have not been able to find a work around it.

I issued following commands:

```
git clone https://github.com/facebook/fblualib.git
cd fblualib/fblualib/python
luarocks make rockspec/*
```

and having the following output: Any help is greatly appreciated as I am really stuck in this error.

```
        cmake -E make_directory build &&
        cd build &&
        cmake -DROCKS_PREFIX=/home/ubuntu/usr/local/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks/fbpython/0.1-1 \
              -DROCKS_LUADIR=/home/ubuntu/usr/local/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks/fbpython/0.1-1/lua \
              -DROCKS_LIBDIR=/home/ubuntu/usr/local/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks/fbpython/0.1-1/lib \
              .. &&
        make

-- Found Torch7 in /home/ubuntu/usr/local/torch/install
-- Boost version: 1.58.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   thread
--   chrono
--   system
--   date_time
--   atomic
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/local/bin/python2.7 (found suitable version "2.7.14", minimum required is "2.7") 
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/local/bin/python2.7 (found version "2.7.14") 
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/ubuntu/usr/src/fblualib/fblualib/python/build
[ 11%] Linking CXX shared module lib.so
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.a(abstract.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `_Py_NotImplementedStruct' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.a: error adding symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/lua_module.dir/build.make:283: recipe for target 'lib.so' failed
make[2]: *** [lib.so] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/lua_module.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/lua_module.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:138: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically I found the issue, it was all fixed by adding `--enable-shared` during python compilation. So I recompiled the python again and it worked. Hope it helps others and prevents them from spending the same time.